# In a topological group all loops based at 1 are homotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fake-proofs

Let G be a topological group and $f,g : [0,1] \times [0,1] \to G$ two loops based at 1.
Why isn't the application $$ H:\begin{array}{rcl}
I \times I & \longrightarrow & G  \\
(t,u) & \mapsto & f(tu)g((1-t)u)
\end{array} $$ an homotopy?

Comment: It is a homotopy, but it is not a homotopy relative the endpoints (i.e. it does not keep the endpoints fixed for all time).

Comment: @C_M Thank you, I was trying to prove that the concatenation $f*g$ and the loop $fg$ are homotopic, and I was confused since my proof didn't use any of their properties. So the question was asking to find an homotopy that fixes the endpoints not just any homotopy. Thanks.

Comment: This would mean that the fundamental group $\pi_1(G,1)$ is trivial for any  topological group. But this is false. Take $G = S^1$.